# Why is my Oracle database link to MSSQL not working after successful creation?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, dblink

I am trying to establish a database link between Oracle, which is installed on a Linux server, and MSSQL, which is installed on a separate Windows server. I have already:

- Successfully tested the DSN
- Queried data from the MSSQL database from the Linux server using isql
  and sqlcmd tools
- Created the initSID.ora file in $ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin
- Configured the listener.ora file and tested if the instance is up
- Configured the tnsnames.ora file and successfully tnsping it.
- Successfully created the database link

However, when I try to use the database link in Oracle to query data from MSSQL, I get the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to an non-Oracle system returned this message: 
ORA-02063: preceding line from DBLINK_NAME
```

**I have checked the following:**

- The Oracle Net Listener is running and configured to listen on the
  correct port.
- The MSSQL server is running and accessible from the Linux server.
- Allowed Remote Connections in MSSQL Server

I am not sure what else to check. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

**Additional information:**

- MSSQL version: 2012
- Oracle version: 12c
- Linux distribution: OEL 7.4
- ODBC driver: dg4odbc ,mssql-tools, libmsodbcsql17
- Error code: ORA-28500, ORA-02063

Edit: I am adding further information that might be useful for investigation:
$ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin/initMSSQL.ora:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = MSSQL
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = user
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.so
HS_FDS_TRACE_FILE_NAME=/tmp/ora_hs_trace.log
HS_NLS_NCHAR = UCS2
```

$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER=
(SID_LIST=
        (SID_DESC=
                (SID_NAME=DBTEST)
                (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1)
                (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
        )
        (SID_DESC=
                (SID_NAME=MSSQL)
                (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1)
                (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
        )
)

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = geno.test)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora:

```
MSSQL =
        (DESCRIPTION =
                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
                (CONNECT_DATA =
                        (SID = MSSQL)
                )
                (HS = OK)
        )
```

I appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: I can't say I've dealt with this same problem myself, but a quick Google search of the error code together with "SQL server" seems to return plenty of results that would likely point you in the right direction.  What have you already researched about that particular error message, and tried (without it resolving your issue)?

Comment: Yes, I've done a lot of research, and so far they point to conclusion that there is a problem with the configuration of ODBC/DSN, or either there is a network problem which are both already solved.